# Pages have different behavior for manual testing and auto testing

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, playwright

I'm using Playwright Framework, gitlab CI.

My problem is that when I'm trying to navigate to the page of the project manually, everything loads fine, when autotest does the same actions, content is not loading.

What can be a troublemaker? There is no cookies or cache problems, no GET, POST etc problems during the testing, somewhy it just doesn't load and that's it.

docker I'm using: https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/atools/chrome-headless/tags

Have tried headed/headless modes, changing the docker, nothing helps.

Can it be GitLab's problem? There is no any specified tokens or accesses for the page which is not loading, it all makes no sense.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: if you go manually to your page you can access the page contents. But with Playwright eg. "npx playwright test" -> page contents are not loaded? what does the page look like in the report when it takes the screenshot, is there an error?

Or is the problem only with the CI-pipeline? so that automated tests work locally with Playwright, but they do not work on CI?

Comment: @ttqa yes, exactly, locally Playwright works fine, during the CI run, some pages can not load content (but it's not stable behavior, anyway devs tell that from their side everything is excellent)

Comment: Is the Gitlab CI runner on cloud or does it use your local agent? Is your application on a specific server like "mysitestaging.com" or do you build the app and use localhost? If your app is behind local firewall, it's clear that a outside CI will not, by default, probably have access to it. Just throwing ideas here. When you run the CI tests, what errors are you getting from Playwright, could you include them in the post? I mean Playwright always has some errors on the log. I think you should add more information about your question :)